# is there a way to keep bookmarks name after converastion

Tags: pdf, ms-word, bookmarks

I am working on MS word 2013 I am converting word doc with bookmarks to pdf, the bookmarks are saved as needed (checkbox text-box etc'..) but the bookmarks names aren't. Is there a way to keep bookmarks name after conversion from word to pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File|Save As>Save As>Type:PDF>Options>Create bookmarks using:Word bookmarks.

Comment: I did it and the bookmarks are saved without their names I'm looking for a way to pass the as well, I need to deal with 548 bookmarks and I want a short way tol deal with them :/

Comment: The bookmark names are saved to the PDF when I do it. Hidden bookmarks aren't saved to the PDF, though, but even then you don't end up with an unnamed bookmark in the PDF.